# Как сгруппировать элементы массива на javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Всем привет.
Допустим у нас есть массив элементов со свойствами name и ID.

```
  var arr = [{
    name: "Dog",
    id: "1"
  }, {
    name: "Cat",
    id: "2"
  }, {
    name: "Dog",
    id: "3"
  }, {
    name: "Cat",
    id: "4"
  }];
```

Необходимо сгруппировать элементы по одинаковым значениям свойства name и добавить их в виде массивов в новый массив?

На выходе должно получиться следующее:

```
  var new_arr = [
    [{
      "name": "Dog",
      "id": "1"
    }, {
      "name": "Dog",
      "id": "3"
    }],
    [{
      "name": "Cat",
      "id": "2"
    }, {
      "name": "Cat",
      "id": "4"
    }]
  ];
```

Значения свойства name динамические

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
  { name: "Dog", id: "1" },
  { name: "Cat", id: "2" },
  { name: "Dog", id: "3" },
  { name: "Cat", id: "4" }
];

var map = arr.reduce((r, i) => {
  r[i.name] = r[i.name] || [];
  r[i.name].push(i); 
  return r;
}, {});
var arr1 = [];
for (var key in map) {
  arr1.push(map[key]);
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Igor, спасибо огромное, огонь!